# How to save value of integer variable in TwinCat3?

Tags: plc, twincat, structured-text

I have a program in TwinCat where 5 integer variables are being updated every 10 seconds to represent the state of 5 pumps. I want to save these values that are being generated into either a textfile or CSV file that I can later extract from the PLC. Code below:

```
IF toninPumpPulse.Q THEN
    rinPump1RPM := (inPump1Count/6)*6; //Pulse sample for 10 seconds. 6 pulses = 1 round.
    inPump1Count := 0; //Reset counter for next 10 second sample
    rinPump2RPM := (inPump2Count/6)*6; //Pulse sample for 10 seconds. 6 pulses = 1 round.
    inPump2Count := 0; //Reset counter for next 10 second sample
    rinPump3RPM := (inPump3Count/6)*6; //Pulse sample for 10 seconds. 6 pulses = 1 round.
    inPump3Count := 0; //Reset counter for next 10 second sample
    rinPump4RPM := (inPump4Count/6)*6; //Pulse sample for 10 seconds. 6 pulses = 1 round.
    inPump4Count := 0; //Reset counter for next 10 second sample
    rinPump5RPM := (inPump5Count/6)*6; //Pulse sample for 10 seconds. 6 pulses = 1 round.
    inPump5Count := 0; //Reset counter for next 10 second sample
```

I am looking to have a new CSV file be created and then populated with the variable values. I am pretty inexperienced in TwinCat and reading the Beckhoff website is not exactly helping as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a combination of several function blocks:

- FB_FileOpen
- FB_FilePuts
- FB_FileClose

All documentation you need + example code is already available on the Beckhoff infosys for this purpose:

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclibutilities/html/tcplclibutilities_csv_sample.htm&id=

Also see this on how to write files in general:
[TwinCAT 3: Write to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431922/twincat-3-write-to-file)

Comment: I am unsure on how to integrate the functions that you have mentioned into my existing code. Do I have to create a empty CSV file in my PLC before hand? Will I be able to create new CSV files every time I run the code that is meant to measure the counts from my pump

Comment: @SaravananMohan the InfoSys link has a complete working example. I suggest you download that one and play around with it.

Comment: I am unable to open the file that was downloaded. It states the file type as a PRO file. Unable to open it using Visual studio and even notepad. Any recommendations?

Comment: It's a TwinCAT 2 file. You have to download TwinCAT 2 and view it. I usually just create a virtual machine for every TwinCAT version I need to test.

Comment: I have used your file writer example as a separate function block being called when needed. The issue I run into is the file open function keeps throwing up an error under fbFileOpen.bErrror. I am unsure of how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: You have all documentation for FB_FileOpen (including all error codes) here:
https://infosys.beckhoff.com/index.php?content=../content/1031/tcplclib_tc2_system/45035996304682507.html&id=

Answer (score 0):

The open source logging library [TcLog](https://github.com/bengeisler/TcLog) may help you. It provides extended logging functionalities to the file system.

I wrote a [blog post](https://benediktgeisler.de/en/blog/tclog/) introducing it, you can also download a precompiled library there.

This is how you would use it in your case:

First, define a static logger instance of type `TcLogCore` that contains the configuration:

```
VAR
  CoreLogger : TcLogCore;
END_VAR

CoreLogger
 .MinimumLevel(E_LogLevel.Warning)
 .WriteToFile('c:\logs\', 'pumpValues.csv')
 .RunLogger();
```

Next, define a logger `TcLog` that actually logs the messages:

```
VAR
  Logger : TcLog;
END_VAR
```

You can use that logger to generate log messages like this:

```
Logger
.OnCondition(toninPumpPulse.Q)
.AppendAny(rinPump1RPM)
.AppendString(',')
.AppendAny(rinPump2RPM)
.AppendString(',')
.AppendAny(rinPump3RPM)
.AppendString(',')
.AppendAny(rinPump4RPM)
.AppendString(',')
.AppendAny(rinPump5RPM)
.ToCustomFormat('');
```

Make sure, `toninPumpPulse.Q` is only `true` for one cycle, otherwise you will generate a load of messages. Have a look at [logging on rising/falling edges](https://benediktgeisler.de/en/blog/tclog/#logging-on-risingfalling-edges) as well.

Since the logger is implemented as Singleton, you can use it anywhere in your program and it will automatically use the configuration of `TcLogCore`.

There are more options in the library, like setting a rolling interval for the log files or automatic deletion of old files that may be useful to you.