# Fixing TwinCAT 3 Problem: FB_FileOpen Busy, State Machine Issue

Tags: state-machine, plc, twincat, structured-text, st

I'm new to Beckhoff/TwinCAT and following tutorials. While making a simple event logger, I hit a snag: after using FB_FileOpen, its bBusy stays True. This jams my state machine in FILE_OPEN. Any ideas on what I messed up? Here's my code:

```
VAR 
    fbFileOpen : FB_FileOpen;
    fbFilePuts : FB_FilePuts;
    RisingEdge : R_TRIG;
    eWriteState : (If_Trigger_Detection,OpenFile_Trigger, OpenFile, WaitForTheEvent,     WriteFileTriggner, WriteFile, CloseFile, Error); 
    stEventWriteToFile: ST_Event;
    
    CsvString : T_MaxString;
    
END_VAR
```

```
RisingEdge(CLK:=TRUE);

CASE eWriteState OF
    If_Trigger_Detection:
        IF RisingEdge.Q THEN 
            eWriteState:=OpenFile_Trigger;
        END_IF 
 
    OpenFile_Trigger:
        fbFileOpen.bExecute := FALSE;
        fbFileOpen(sPathName:= 'C:\TwinCAT\Eventslog.txt',nMode:=FOPEN_MODEAPPEND OR FOPEN_MODETEXT,bExecute := TRUE);
        eWriteState:= OpenFile;
        
    OpenFile:
        fbFileOpen.bExecute := FALSE;
        IF fbFileOpen.bError THEN
            eWriteState := Error;   
                 
        ELSIF NOT fbFileOpen.bBusy AND fbFileOpen.hFile <>0 THEN 
            eWriteState:= WaitForTheEvent;
            
        END_IF
        
        
    WaitForTheEvent:
        //do nothing just wait
    
    WriteFileTriggner:
    CsvString := CreateCsvString (stEvent:= stEventWriteToFile);
    //fbFilePuts(bExecute:=FALSE,
    //          sLine:=CsvString);
    fbFilePuts.bExecute:=FALSE;
    fbFilePuts(sLine := CsvString,bExecute := TRUE); 
    eWriteState := WriteFile;
    WriteFile:
    fbFilePuts(bExecute := FALSE);
    IF NOT fbFilePuts.bBusy THEN 
        eWriteState := WaitForTheEvent;
    END_IF

    //CloseFile:
    
    Error:
    //Here we will write the code for error Handling
END_CASE
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rikpD.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep calling `fbFileOpen()` also in the `OpenFile`-state. Right now you're only setting the `bExecute`-flag to `FALSE`, but you're not actually calling the body of the function block, which means it is never executed, and thus stays in busy.
Simply replace:

```
fbFileOpen.bExecute := FALSE;
```

with

```
fbFileOpen(bExecute := FALSE);
```

Also, this question has already been answered here:
[TwinCAT 3: Write to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431922/twincat-3-write-to-file/49435166#49435166)